# Storing an observer in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, p5.js

I am building my first website using Vue.js and Vuex.
One of my goals is to display canvasses made with P5.js.

**Here's what is working already**
After calling new p5('someScript', 'someElementID') I get a p5 object (let's call it p5Canvas).
One way to destroy it would be to call remove() from within someScript.
Another one would be to call this function from outside the script using p5Canvas.destroy().

**Here's the issue**
Now in this particular case I would like the destruction to be triggered by a different component and I thought storing p5Canvas in Vuex could be an easy method of passing on the object.

when calling p5Canvas.destroy() on the object retrieved from the Vuex Store. I get that destroy is not a function. When I print the objects, the original shows as p5 {..} and the Vuex copy shows as `{__ob__: Observer}`

Indeed, upon inspection of the element, some 'wrapper'  functions aren't available... I would like to learn why I cannot just pass the entire original object like this?

Thanks for reading this far :-)

Comment: I don't know why. but why not just store `p5Canvas` as a global variable. like `window.p5Canvas = ...`. Vuex is for reactive data and can trigger DOM updates whenever its value changes. `p5Canvas` should not be reactive.

Comment: Thanks Jacob!
I jumped straight to Vue.js after some basic JQuery dabbling...So I'm still playing around with questions about how Vue.js was designed to be used... window.p5Canvas works, and I will use it for now. :-)
Besides being functional, do you think it fits in as a neat design? It seems to totally neglect the entire library by not using component composition, nor does it fit in the "action/view/state" concept if I ony use it for canvasses.

Comment: perhaps a neat way would be to put everything related to this canvas into 1 single component and control it by passing props/event into this component.